# Php (table using array)

Tags: php, html, html-table

How would I make a table that takes a PHP array. The array is decided by a html input. The table has the actual values in the first column, length in the second column, and if it starts with 3 letters, 3 numbers or neither in the third column.

```
echo '<table>';
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        echo '<tr><td>';
        echo htmlspecialchars($array);
        echo '</td><td>';
        echo strlen($array);
        echo '</td><td>';

            //to work on
            $trim = substr($array, 0, 3);
                if(is_numeric($trim)){
                    echo 'numeric';
                }elseif(is_string($trim)){
                    echo 'string';
                }else{
                    echo 'else ?';
                }

        echo '</td></tr>';
        }
    echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP will interpret POST values with brackets in their name as arrays.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="values[]" >
    <input type="text" name="values[]" >
    <input type="text" name="values[]" >
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Now... The solution presented here is only to get you started. The third column can be a bit tricky because a value of '*ab123c*' will pass as string.

I will let you work the kinks the way you want them to be handled.

```
if(is_array($_POST['values'])){
    echo '<table>';
        foreach ($_POST['values'] as $key => $value) {
            echo '<tr><td>';
            echo htmlspecialchars($value);
            echo '</td><td>';
            echo strlen($value);
            echo '</td><td>';

                //to work on
                $trim = substr($value, 0, 3);
                    if(is_numeric($trim)){
                        echo 'numeric';
                    }elseif(is_string($trim)){
                        echo 'string';
                    }else{
                        echo 'else ?';
                    }

            echo '</td></tr>';
            }
        echo '</table>';
}
```

**PS:** Never trust user input ;)

I know the code is not squeaky clean, the goal was for it to be easy to understand.

Comment: How would this work if only on text field is present. And i have already got the array using the php explode function

Comment: In that case you could use the array resulted from the `explode()` and replace the `$_POST['values']` using only the  `foreach` part.

Comment: `explode` will store exploded values `[0]=value` 

You could use `print_r($array)` to see what the array looks like

Comment: Thank you. I added the code I got. Can you look at it?

Comment: `$array` should only be used to initiate the `foreach` all the other ones should be replaced by `$value`

Comment: Glad I could help !
@NatheeshSelvan Please don't forget to accept my answer... :D